# Playback during Copying

Tags: macos, leopard, uti, copy-paste, file-transfer

When I copied a movie over the Network, via Finder, back in 10.5 I could simply open it in VLC during copying. However on 10.7 it tells me the file is used by OS X and could, therefore, not be opened. Is there a way to do this in Lion as well?